# maven: Synchronize the execution of non-thread-safe plugins

Tags: maven, maven-3

In my multi-module maven project I use a plugin which is not thread-safe. Unfortunately this forces me to build the project sequentially.

Is it possible to instruct maven to synchronize the execution of the plugin?

To be mor eprecise: I would like to run the build in parallel, but whenever one thread executes the non-thread-safe plugin it should lock it, so other threads need to wait for the other thread to complete the plugin execution.

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards

Oliver

Comment: First which plugin? Second you have to change the plugin...I suppose you get a `WARNING...`

Comment: Plugin in question is the frontend-maven-plugin: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Well, I thought about having a genrel way in maven to synchronize those non-thread-safe plugins.

For sure it makes much more sense to adjust the plugin, but that's not always possible.

Comment: Hm..the frontend-maven-plugin has been marked with threadSafe=true so can you please post the message you get? Also which Maven versions you are using and JDK etc.

Comment: It's not a problem of the frontend-maven-plugin itself... it's a problem of the process the plugin executes (pnpm).

Comment: Please post the output/error messages etc...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise,
sorry for answering that late.

I created a reproducer: https://github.com/OLibutzki/frontend-sample/actions/runs/3189879478

As you can see we use pnpm to build the frontend. Although the maven-Plugin can run it concurrentlsy pnpm cannot handle it. Therefore I would like to configure maven in order to execute the plugin sequentially.

Comment: The error `Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:pnpm (install-node-dependencies) on project frontend-module3: Failed to run task: 'pnpm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]` shows that the tool pnpm is not on your machine...

Comment: No, it's because the tool has a problem with concurrent installs.